# How to destruct a exist in goal for coq

Tags: coq

This is a bit generic so feel free to ask for details, I simplified to make the problem easier to communicate.

Say my goal is

```
let (r,_) := f x in Q r
```

where `f x` has type `{u | P u}`.

I want to "destruct" this so that I have `Q r`
as the goal with `P r` as a hypothesis. What is the best way to achieve this ?
In the past, I have achieved what I wanted by

```
pose (f x).
```

and then simplifying.

Per request here is some simplified code.

```
Parameter T:Type.
Parameter P:T -> Prop.

Axiom A : {t:T|P t}.

Definition myvar:T.
  destruct A.
  exact x.
Defined.
Theorem B : P myvar.
```

Comment: It seems I don't get your issue at all. If my answer is not targeting the real problem, could you explain your issue in more detail please ?

Answer (score 3):

```
unfold myvar; destruct A.
```

will solve your goal in this particular case.

In general, the `destruct` tactic can be used with with any term and it will try to abstract the term out and destruct it. However, note that this may fail sometimes, particularly when using dependent types.

The reason is that `destruct` uses the gallina `match` underneath, and in Coq, pattern matching may lose some typing information if not done carefully, search for "Convoy Pattern" for more information.

Comment: This comment will seem silly, but can I make coq infer A? In my use case, A is not an axiom but rather complicated, but the type is still like my example.

Comment: Sure you could use ltac's `match _ ` for that; alternatively you can use `set t := pat` to alias complex patterns using matching.

Answer (score 0):

You can name the 'outputs' of a `destruct` tactic if you want:

```
(* Stupid definitions to create a minimal example *)
Parameter A: Set.
Parameter P Q: A -> Prop.
Definition f (x: A) : {r | P r }.
Admitted.

Goal (forall x, let (r, _) := f x in Q r).
intro x.
destruct f as [r hr]. (* you goal has now r: A and hr : P r as premises *)
Abort.
```

Edit: more info after comment.
If you don't name them, Coq will do it automatically for you using a scheme based on `xi` variables (`x0, x1, ...`). You can only force the naming of the first variable if you don't care about the name of the second part using `destruct f as [r].`

Comment: How does this help?  If you don't name them explicitly Coq will name them automatically.

Comment: The OP asked how he could have `Q r` in the goal and `P r` in the context. If you don't name them, Coq will indeed name them, but using `x0` (depending on the context...) but not `r`. I'm just answering the question here. You can only name the first one if you really need, but I usually name all or none of `destruct` 's outputs.

Comment: I don't think the OP's question is "How to name the premises generated by `destruct`?"

Comment: Then I don't understand the question